# tsearch and tfind

Tags: c, binary-tree, glibc

Given sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(int), is it safe to collect ints in tree with

```
void *map=0; 
tsearch(42, &map, int_cmp);
```

?

I get segfault and I see no flaws in code other then that unusial usage.

EDIT: Of course, I am not derefencing pointer, only convert back to int.
Idea is that int can be fitted into void* variable, so i have no need for heap allocation.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter to [tsearch](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/tsearc.html) must be a pointer.  In this case the number 42 is interpreted as a pointer, hence the segfault.  Try:

```
void *map=0;
int key = 42;  
tsearch(&key, &map, int_cmp);
```

Comment: That doesn't store 42, that stores a pointer to key. tsearch does not dereference the pointer, it stores it as-is.

Comment: @Ariel If you read the description of tsearch (e.g. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.bpxbd00/rtsear.htm ), you will see that the first parameter ('key') is a pointer to a value, of which the returned node in the tree is created (if necessary)

Comment: I know it's confusing. But it actually stores that *pointer* in the tree. NOT the thing pointed to by it! You can store integers in there if you like, if you cast them to `(void *)` it doesn't care.

Comment: I guess you are correct, but only if you use the appropriate comparison function as well (that compares its two values as-is and does not dereference them), but that is not the intended use (that is this use is a hack and is not guaranteed to work on all platforms)

Comment: It will work everywhere as long as the data type you store fits in a `void *`. Your compiler should warn if it doesn't fit. The tsearch does not care what you send it, it just saves the number as is.